# Where date between a and b performance

Tags: sql, oracle

I have come across a query which has me curious whether the programmer was show boating or whether there is merit to the way it has been done in terms of performance. I have no clue as to why the from time is 01:59 rather than 00:00, this would actually remove some of the results that would actually want to be included.

This is the where clause of the query

```
WHERE REPORTDATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 21) + 01 / 24 + 59 / (24 * 60) + 59 / (24 * 60 * 60)
                  AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 23 / 24 + 59 / (24 * 60) + 59 / (24 * 60 * 60)
```

and if my math is correct, is the same as

```
WHERE REPORTDATE BETWEEN to_date('13/04/2017 01:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
              AND to_date('04/05/2017 23:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

Is there any benefit in the first calculated where clause over the second?

Comment: I can't imagine a way that the first query could be more efficient, but I don't know Oracle inside out. Is it possible to ask the person who wrote the original query? There are a lot of developers who are not very strong in SQL, who aren't even aware of date functions within SQL.

Comment: The first one doesn't have to be rewritten if you run it on a different day.

Comment: Have you tried to generate the explain plain of both to actually see the differences?

Comment: You should investigate the significance of 01:59.  Maybe it's a mistake.

Comment: Your maths isn't quite correct, you've lost the seconds; the first filter is 2017-04-13 01:59:59 to 2017-05-04 23:59:59. (Personally I'd prefer to not use between for dates; the start time needs to be clarified, but the end could be simplified to `< TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1`.)

Comment: In general terms, any date handling routine that assumes 24 hours per day is broken by design. I don't think the performance gain (if any) is worth if results are incorrect.

Comment: There should be no difference in performance (none that you can detect anyway). The arithmetic operations are trivial, and since the arithmetic expression is the same for all rows in your input, the calculations are performed only once (!!) The difference, as Dan has already explained, is that one version has a variable date while your re-write has a hardcoded date. Beyond that, like Alex, I would use >= and < and such instead of `between`. On the other hand, I **would** use `trunc(sysdate) + 2/24` if I wanted 2:00:00 AM on sysdate - I don't understand Alvaro's objection to this.

Comment: @mathguy It's point #1 in [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - that is a bogus argument. Date arithmetic in Oracle does not assume every day has 24 hours. The computation `trunc(sysdate) + 2/24` will produce the time-of-day component 02:00:00 AM regardless of whether SYSDATE has 24, 23, or 25 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use interval literals to get rid of all the arithmetic and simplify the query:

```
WHERE REPORTDATE BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '20 22:00:01' DAY TO SECOND
                 AND     TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '00 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND
```

or

```
WHERE REPORTDATE BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '21' DAY
                                          + INTERVAL '01:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
                 AND     TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '00 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND
```

or

```
WHERE REPORTDATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '20 22:00:01' DAY TO SECOND
AND   REPORTDATE <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to imagine a performance difference, based on different ways of calculating constants in a query.

I would write this using something like this:

```
WHERE REPORTDATE >= CAST(TIMESTAMP '2017-04-13 02:00:00' as DATE) and
      REPORTDATE < DATE '2017-05-05'
```

If you are going to include date/time constants, use the built-in mechanisms that support standard formats.

or for more flexibility based on the current date:

```
WHERE REPORTDATE >= TRUNC(sysdate) - 21 + 2 / 24 AND
      REPORTDATE < TRUNC(sysdate) + 1
```

(or, if 1:59 is really intended . . . then `TRUNC(sysdate) - 21 + (1 * 60 + 59) / (24 * 60)`.)